# Problema ao setar um objeto de um ejb remoto

Tags: java, ejb

Estou com problema ao usar um Set de um objeto de um EJB remoto, esse objeto será enviado para o mesmo EJB e lá fará uma conexão com o banco ou um webservice(Por ser uma aplicação da empresa não posso colocar o código aqui, por isso colocarei um exemplo).

Ex:

```
 ClasseDTODoEJB.setAtributo1("StringAleatoria");//Recebe o valor normalmente
 ClasseDTODoEJB.setAtributo2("StringAleatoria");//Causa um erro apesar de receber string e não possuir uma regra de negócio

 ClasseWebServiceDoEJB.ChamaWebService(ClasseDTODoEJB);//Classe que recebe o DTO pra fazer alguma tarefa ao qual não possuo acesso
```

Tentei criar um DTO igual na aplicação local e usar BeanUtils.CopyProperties() pra copiar o valor de um para ou outro porém os atributos não são passados corretamente apesar das duas classes serem iguais e a local estar recebendo todos os atributos. Isso pode ser algum erro no build path? O jar está declarado lá e no tomcat no shared.loader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema estava no shared.loader do Tomcat, eu acabei esquecendo de adicionar o caminho desse EJB.